# Android : Print html document from WebView

Tags: android, printing, webview

I'v read that the WebView in Android is a simple browser based on webkit and I was thinking that calling window.print() from my html document will be handled by this "mini-browser". 
But no. 
After reading many things on that subject, it seems that it's only possible to call a print function from the android app, and not from the html document, and this parti is poorly documented.

Has anyone experienced this before ?

Thanks.

Comment: The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html) explicitly says _"You cannot use JavaScript in a HTML document to trigger printing"_, and provides an example of how to use the Java API. Chrome for Android (at least Beta) supports `window.print()`.

Comment: Thank you. That perfectly anwser my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks, @martync! Reposting my comment as an answer, as it has turned out to actually answer the question.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html) explicitly says *"You cannot use JavaScript in a HTML document to trigger printing"*, and provides an example of how to use the Java API. Chrome for Android (at least Beta) supports `window.print()`.