# Print button on webview is not working

Tags: xamarin, webview

I have a webpage that has a "Print" button and works normally when using Any Browser on mobile phone. 
But when using the webview, is not working. Its like not firing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016230/android-print-html-document-from-webview

Comment: Houston, I think I have a problem ! @SushiHangover

Answer (score 0):

For java

```
private void createWebPrintJob(WebView webView) { 

PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE); 
PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter(); 

String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Print Test"; 
printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter, new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
 }

 //perform click pdf creation operation on click of print button click 
// Use this on main activity class tag

public void printPDF(View view) { createWebPrintJob(myWebView); }
```

For Xml Create Button

```
android:onClick="printPDF"
```